# Cannot see the database that is created in phpmyadmin in mysql(and vice versa)

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When I created a database 'website' in phpMyAdmin then created a connection.php for a website, and when I tested the website, it displayed SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'website'

Then I checked in the mysql console and the database 'website' is unknown.

(Then it was the same:
Again I created a database in the mysql console but it didn't show up in phpmyadmin)

Comment: Check that you have the same user. You can do this with the query `SELECT CURRENT_USER();` Check in phpMyAdmin and mysql console.

Comment: @VMai, both have displayed root@localhost. I don't understand, it is the same user.

Comment: Do you operate on two different hosts? You could check the result of `SELECT @@hostname;` both in phpMyAdmin and mysql console.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I see that my hostname, 'Lee-PC' is both on phpmyadmin and mysql. What does this mean?

Comment: With which command did you create your database?

Comment: Oh sorry, in SELECT @@hostname in both phpmyadmin and mysql, it displayed 'Lee-PC'. But in SELECT CURRENT_USER(), it displayed root@localhost. So I think I operate on 2 hosts?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. 
if you have created the database in phpMyAdmin **correctly** try this
copy your website folder and store it in **c:\wamp\www** and go to *localhost* and see your project is displaying. then try your
        connection.php